# Xcode shows wrong code when I clone project from gitlab

Tags: xcode, git, gitlab

when I clone project from gitlab and open it with Xcode, I see wrong codes in the project
and when I open that file with visual studio I see correct codes

[image]

just pay attention to line 286
does anybody face this problem?
and, how can I fix my Xcode?

Comment: I am looking at line 286 in both photos and I see no material difference other than highlighting colors. Can you explain exactly what is "wrong" with the code in the xcode version?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at link 286, there are 19 “=“ in both photos.

The difference is due to use of proportional vs non-proportional fonts.